# Wordpress — display events (custom post type) for the current week (from monday to sunday included)

Tags: wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I'm working on a wordpress of a soccer club and I want to display events (matches) for the current week.

I have to sort by ACF field called "date_match" and not the date of the post itself but it doesn't work.

Matches are custom post type.

Here is my query

```
<?php
    //define args
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'matchs',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'          => 'date_match',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'    => 4,
        // Using the date_query to filter posts from last week
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'date_match',
                'year' => date( 'Y' ),
                'week' => date( 'W' )
            )
        )

    );
    //query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    //loop
    if ($the_query->have_posts()): while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
…
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article>
        <h6>No match to display.</h6>
    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

And here is my configuration in ACF :

[image: ACF configuration]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$start = 'define your start date';
$end = 'define your end date';

// update your meta_query to search for posts between start and end
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'date_match',
        'value' => array($start, $end),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )
```

Comment: Hello Mikerojas ! Thanks for the tip. It takes me to the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//define args
//timestamp used to format the date
$thisMonday = strtotime('this week');
$thisFriday = strtotime('+6 days', $thisMonday);

$thisMonday = date('Ymd', $thisMonday);
$thisFriday = date('Ymd', $thisFriday);

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'matchs',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'          => 'date_match',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    // Using the date_query to filter posts from this week
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_match',
            'value' => $thisMonday,
            'compare' => '>='
            ),
        array(
            'key' => 'date_match',
            'value' => $thisFriday,
            'compare' => '<='
        )
    )

);
//query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

//loop
if ($the_query->have_posts()): while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
```

?>